# Sticky footer in ember

Tags: css, ember.js

Hey I create Ember application , And I try to set `Sticky Footer`.
I try to do this by this tutorial [Sticky Footer On CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/) , Cause it's work for me once.
But with Ember its dosen't work

My css:

```
.mainFooter {
     height:100px;
     color:white;
     background-color: #0c2635;
     text-align:center;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
}
.wrapper:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
.mainFooter, .wrapper:after {
    height: 100px;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<footer class="mainFooter">
    SOME TEXT
</footer>
```

As I said, it's dosent work.
I watch the source code via the Inspector and I saw that Ember added its own wrapper to content the I put in the `application.hbs` file, this wrapper have a class named `ember-view` so I try to do:

```
.ember-view {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

But it's dosent work either, the footer displayed in the middle of the page.
Someone maybe try this and successid?
I would like to know about a solution to this problem.

I don't know how to fake an Ember app in jsfiddle/codeopen so I upload the app to my server, url: http://drawyourgif.pe.hu/dist/

**EDIT**
According to the solution that `kumkanillam` sugest I did so:

Application.hbs:

```
{{outlet "modal"}}
{{partial "header"}}
<div id="gif" class="wrapper">
    {{outlet}}
</div>
{{partial "footer"}}
```

app.js

```
App = Ember.Application.extend({
    modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix,
    podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix,
    rootElement: '#gif',
    Resolver
});
```

And I get this error in the console:

```
ember.debug.js:43272Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of undefined
```

What I did wrong?

Comment: Could post a codepen/jsbin?  Also, this problem is solved cleanly/easily with flexbox.  Are you open to using flexbox?

Comment: @sheepdog Hey , I dont care using flexbox, just its works, Look at my edit I added the site url that you can see the problem

Comment: @Harmanmet  I applied css style `position: fixed;
    bottom: -3px;
    left: 2px;
    right: 2px;` to `.wrapper:after` it worked in your site. you can try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.ember-view` will be included for all ember component by default so it's not good to apply css property for this class.

there may be many ways but the below should help.

You can wrap your `application.hbs` to render inside your `page-wrap` div.

for this you need to include the below line in
**index.html**

```
<div id="app-name" class="wrapper">
    {{content-for "body"}}
</div>
```

**`application.hbs`**

```
<h1> Content </h1>
{{outlet}}  
<div id="footer">
  <p>I'm the Sticky Footer. inside application.hbs</p>    
</div>
```

Configure `rootElement` in `app.js`. that will force entire app to include it in `app-name` div.

**`app.js`**

```
App = Ember.Application.extend({
    modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix,
    podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix,
    rootElement: '#app-name',
    Resolver
});
```

**`app.css`**

```
#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3px;
    left: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: #fff;
}
```

## Final Update:

You don't need to change anything in app.js. just look at the sample twiddle. I think this will help you 
 [SAMPLE TWIDDLE](https://ember-twiddle.com/af348780654847149afe768e47f77566?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C)

Comment: Hey @kumkanillam I did like you said and its throw me an error, look at my edit to see more details please

Comment: @Harmanmet instead of application.hbs mention it in index.html

Comment: And what about `link-to` helpers, they work in the footer if I put them out side the root element?

Comment: it won't work. Plain html only it will work. for link-to you can use normal anchor tag. ..if that's not aligned with your requirement, then we should try figuring out to include footer stuff in application.hbs..

Comment: @Harmanmet I updated my answers with [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/af348780654847149afe768e47f77566?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C). You can't close application.hbs wrapper div inside application.hbs and open footer class. followed different trick to add sticky footer. I hope this will be helpful to you. good luck.

Comment: @kumkanillam `position: absolute;` only works if the page content is less that the viewport.  Otherwise the content runs on below the footer.

Comment: @sheepdog I guess OP requested sticky footer so `position:fixed` will do the trick right ?

Comment: @kumkanillam I added some content to your code to show what happens: https://ember-twiddle.com/f620502b8172f4181c9d58503e02e39c?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C

Comment: Now I understood what do you mean. thank you. but then changing position from absolute to fixed. looks right updated [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/7da2cde0590b767ec3cdb33a2afa4e7e?openFiles=styles.app.css%2C)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses flexbox.  You may not want to use flexbox because you're unfamiliar with it, but I'll submit this answer for later google searches.

Here's a codepen with very little content in the main body: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgXgjV

Here's the same css with much more content in the main area: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpVpBK

Here is an example of why `position: absolute` doesn't work: https://ember-twiddle.com/f620502b8172f4181c9d58503e02e39c?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C

## HTML

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="root" class="ember-application">
    <div id="ember332" class="ember-view">
      <div class='main-content'>
      <h1>Welcome to Ember Twiddle</h1>
        <br />

        <p>
          this page has very little content
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
        <p>I'm the Sticky Footer. inside application.hbs</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

## CSS

```
/* this is just to reset codepen */
/* probably not necessary on ember */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* end reset */


html, body, #root {
  height: 100%;
}

.ember-view {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: lightblue;
}

.main-content {
  flex: 1;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```